# How to Apply "Mirror Effect/Horizontal Flip" to the Agora Live Video Streaming using AgoraRtcRawData

Tags: flutter, dart, video-streaming, agora.io, agora

I am using AgoraRtcRawData to process the VideoFrames of Live Vide Streamnig. I usually register the videoframeobserver like this:

```
await AgoraRtcRawdata.registerAudioFrameObserver(handle);
     await AgoraRtcRawdata.registerVideoFrameObserver(handle,);
```

Now, I know that AgoraRtcRawData supports Mirror Effect as it has a method named "getMirrorApplied" but it isn't implemented inside AgoraRtcRawDataPlugin class. now how can i implement it to use it via methodChannel inside Flutter.